# How to define a YouTube History Search Engine in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I have defined a Search Engine in Google Chrome ("Version 112.0.5615.49 (Official Build) (64-bit)"):

[image]

But it does not work the way it should. Trying it out via:

```
yth automation
```

It goes to https://www.youtube.com/feed/history and not what I would have expected it to.

Now, if I then find the search field, on the above https://www.youtube.com/feed/history page, and type in "automation", and press the return key, I get a URL that I would have expected:

https://www.youtube.com/feed/history?query=automation

So how do I make this Quick Search to work as expected, which is **not** requiring me to do a two step operation, first to go to https://www.youtube.com/feed/history, and then type in the phrase in that field?  The whole point of quick searches are to save time and finger presses.

Comment: Typing a search term in https://www.youtube.com/feed/history and pressing enter, I was redirected to `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=` followed by the search term. I think that you should use `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%s`. I'm using Chrome for Mac, version `Version 112.0.5615.137 (Official Build) (arm64)`. If  you need further help, please add more details like if you are using a Chrome profile linked to a Google account, the type of Google account (consumer or Google Workspace), if you are using Google account multiple sign in or you are signed, etc.

Comment: @Rubén Unfortunately, that does a search of YouTube, not a search in my YouTube watch history.  Thanks for that attempt, as this is rather frustrating that this does not work out of the box.